# Is it correct to say - " underwent pleasure "

Tags: sentence-meaning, sentence-choice, sentence-usage

Is it correct to say -

> I underwent great pleasure listening to your song, nothing could make it better.

I doubt if the above is correct, so I would say this instead-

> I experienced great pleasure listening to your song, nothing could make it better.

I think this is grammatically correct, but it doesn't sound informal and rather sounds archaic.

If I am right in thinking so, is there a better way to express the same compliment.

Comment: Definitely not - you _undergo_ an unpleasant experience! To say _I experienced great pleasure_ is correct but very formal; you could say _Your song gave me great pleasure_ or, more informal still, something like _I really enjoyed it._

Comment: @KateBunting    But how should I use undergo with ' I ' ?

Comment: _I am to undergo surgery tomorrow. He underwent severe thirst in the desert._

Comment: @KateBunting That was very useful, Thanks !

Comment: @KateBunting There is nothing strictly wrong with saying that you [undergo](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/undergo) something pleasurable. It's just not something we *typically* say. For example, women in the 19th century *underwent* medical procedures to relieve themselves of stress. (I.e., doctors brought them to orgasm; this was before we came to understand and accept what was happening.) The fact that they gained pleasure from it doesn't invalidate the use of *undergo*.